# Error when cropping a layer mask (raster)

Tags: qgis, raster

I'm trying to crop an image using the mask layer to make a slope map and relief analysis, but every time I try, these errors appear, as shown in the images below.

[image]

Comment: Hi Laura. Please replace the image with a proper screenshot when you can.

Comment: Looks like you are missing an image (or two). You may need to translate the error messages into English for the purposes of this site (ie screenshots won't be in English).